# How to check if urls is already open HTML

Tags: html, css

I was working on a mini website project using django. I found bootstrap a while ago and started using some of their features. One that I really liked was the dropdown button.

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="home/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact/">Contact me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

But I was having a unexpected "error"/bug. When I click on one of those buttons it will add its href to the url.

And here comes the problem. It will add the href even if the url already contains it. How can I solve this problem and where. On django scripts or with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

It looks to me like everything is behaving as it should technically, the problem is with the href target itself.

Since you have a relative link not an absolute one, it assumes it target is relative to the page you are on.

**Potential Solutions**

1 - Use an absolute link in this case.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.youwebsite.com/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.youwebsite.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.youwebsite.com/contact/">Contact me</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

2 - Use the base tag.

This will set a root url for your website, it may cause unexpected results so check and re-check if you use this solution.

[HTML Base Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: But imagine that the website is a social media style where people have profiles. So I wanted to add /blog after the id of the profile without dublicating it. I can't do that with an absolute link. I think I should have explained better.

Comment: Thats fine, just have php or your backend code generate a complete absolute link.$link = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/'.$userid.'/blog/';